# How to login facebook in my application?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

I am developing a cross platform application using **phonegap**(HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript), and I want to give a choice for users to login to **facebook**, and start chatting on a public room using their **facebook** account. how could I implement this?

Comment: Please, add some context, what have you done already ? As-is, the question is too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far too open ended. Typically, you need to have a specific technical issue. But take a look at http://plugreg.com/plugin/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.